# Creating Trash for shared NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, 20.04, trash

Is there a way to create a trash for the shared NTFS partition with Windows. Whenever I delete something, It says that it can't be moved to the trash and will be deleted immediately.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=88905181-e735-4dd4-be4f-c90da558dc32 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=903A-A250  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D60CFF0BF1D440 /mnt/01D60CFF0BF1D440 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: I’ve never tried to do this myself and wouldn’t be surprised if it wasn’t possible, however it seems it is. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366388/how-can-i-enable-trash-feature-in-a-ntfs-partition-with-permissions

Comment: @PonJar I still don't understand what I have to do? Do I just copy-paste that code? Also which code should I use?

Comment: You need to interpret the answer and apply the principles to your situation. In this case the NTFS partition has been mounted at /media/FILES. Where is your NTFS partition mounted? In that FILES folder there was a dot folder .trash-1000. To see if you have one navigate to where your partition is mounted and turn on hidden files in the file manager view options. Dot files and folders are like any other file or folder but hidden to some degree. If you have a folder like this and want to follow the answer you just need to delete it although I would look inside first to see what you are deleting

Comment: @PonJar There is no such folder.

Comment: Ok, I can only suggest you search this forum and via a search engine for a solution

Comment: Others have fixed this here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499345

Comment: @PonJar What should I do to this. I have updated the question with the fstab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you change the final line of your /etc/fstab file with the following:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D60CFF0BF1D440              /mnt/Windows          ntfs-3g users,uid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137,x-gvfs-show,utf8 0 0
```

The uid, dmask and fmask options are setting the security options on the ntfs file system. They should be fine for you. The utf8 option helps manage file names between Windows and Linux. For this to work you will need a mount point at /mnt/Windows, which is simpler than what you currently have:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/Windows
```

To edit your fstab file use:

`sudo nano -B /etc/fstab`

This will create a backup copy of the original fstab. Let us know how you get on

Comment: It worked alright. Thanks.