# Neither files nor subfolders in my disk partition are accessible

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am a new Ubuntu user. I have version 20.04.1 LTS on a new Lenovo Legion computer.

The problem (among dozens) that I have is that neither the files nor the subfolders in my disk partition are accessible after I turn on the computer. That is, after I open, say, a Text Editor, I go into the 'recent files' to open one of the files on this partition, and I can only see a blank file. Similarly, while, upon opening, Document Viewer typically displays recently used files, the files from this partition are missing. Finally, when I open Files Manager, when I click on any of the bookmarks directing to some folder in this unfortunate partition, I only get warning: "Oops! something went wrong. Unable to find the requested file. Please check spelling and try again."

In a given session, only after I open this partition with a File Manager by once left-clicking on it (named "700 GB Volume"), these problems vanish. From the view of the Files Manager I see that after opening the partition, the information next to it changes, based on this I can only suppose that it is only upon opening that this partition mounts.

[here's the screenshot of the view before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qc8R.png)

[here's the screenshot of the view after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaJPO.png)

Another thing is that partition has a strange name "a9c60f12-2bb0-4085-bf36-d47d2d945c33" I didn't give. And I don't know how to change it.

I thought that these problems might be related to the apparent fact that the Partition ownership was not mine (this is what I've read in the properties of the folder in Files Manager), but I changed the ownership after using the command

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/piotrek/a9c60f12-2bb0-4085-bf36-d47d2d945c33
```

I changed the permission to everyone to be able to do everything with the contents of this partition. However, even though after rebooting I see no information that I don't have the ownership of the folder (so I suspect I permanently became its proper owner), I still have the exact same problems with accessing the contents of the Partition.

Maybe the problem is related to the fact that this partition is the only one I haven't formatted after reinstallation of Ubuntu. Initially, it was in a "Computer" folder in the Files Manager, but after reinstallation it appears next to the "Computer" folder in the Files Manager with the apparent directory: "/media/piotrek". In general, the partitions are: 74GB bootable with operating system and programs that I install, 700GB (this unfortunate partition with all my files), Swap 64GB, 186GB mounted at /home.

EDIT:
As suggested by the user **PonJar**, I add the output of **lsblk** below:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0 233.5M  1 loop /snap/atom/259
loop1         7:1    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop2         7:2    0  96.6M  1 loop /snap/core/9804
loop3         7:3    0    61M  1 loop /snap/core20/634
loop4         7:4    0   251M  1 loop /snap/gimp/292
loop5         7:5    0 255.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop6         7:6    0   140K  1 loop /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
loop7         7:7    0  55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop8         7:8    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop9         7:9    0   127M  1 loop /snap/pinta-james-carroll/4
loop10        7:10   0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8790
loop11        7:11   0 161.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
loop12        7:12   0 177.4M  1 loop /snap/skype/143
loop13        7:13   0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/467
loop14        7:14   0 260.7M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
loop15        7:15   0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop16        7:16   0  71.2M  1 loop /snap/walc/17
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  68.9G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0  59.8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 651.9G  0 part /media/piotrek/a9c60f12-2bb0-4085-bf36-d47
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 173.2G  0 part /home
```

I also append the contents of **/etc/fstab** file if that can be helpful to give me an advice:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=9eee989f-2676-4f2f-9dd3-bb654c3d9f78 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
UUID=f4085257-d7d6-43b4-b19c-332fe4472e99 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=90c20dba-439c-480b-b253-dfbeaa7ad441 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: When you click on the 700GB partition in the file manager the partition will be mounted somewhere below /media. The odd name you see is probably the UUID of the 700GB partition. You need to add an entry in your /etc/fstab file to make it mount at boot time to a location of your choosing. If you need more help with that add the output of lsblk to your question

Comment: Thanks for that PonJar, but I really need more help with that. I've added what you suggested. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a convenient mount point. This should just be an empty directory such as

```
/data
```

or

```
/home/username/data
```

You create it by opening a terminal, then:

```
mkdir data
```

The command above will make the empty data folder in your home directory. If you want it at /data:

```
cd /
sudo mkdir data
```

You then need to edit your fstab file but make a backup copy first:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak 
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the following to the end of the fstab file

```
UUID=a9c60f12-2bb0-4085-bf36-d47d2d945c33       /home/username/data               ext4            rw,relatime     0 0
```

This assumes a9c60f12-2bb0-4085-bf36-d47d2d945c33 is the UUID of the 700GB partition. You can check with

```
sudo blkid
```

Change the /home/username/data entry to match your username and choice of mount point.
Change the ext4 entry according to the filesystem format on the 700GB partition. See the man page for mount for details.
If your partition is formatted in NTFS see this answer for the details you will need. [Creating Trash for shared NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235979/creating-trash-for-shared-ntfs-partition/1237000#1237000)

When you have finished editing and saved fstab the following will mount the new entry and is useful as a check that the editing is correct.

```
mount -a
```

You should have no errors and gain access to your files in the chosen location.

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: "Seem the man page for mount for details." I have never installed Windows on this computer, so I guess my partition was not formatted in NTFS and when I checked with "Disks" application, my partition had ext4 filesystem. Otherwise, I did everything as you instructed and so far it works beautifully, many thanks for that!

Comment: Glad it worked :) A man page is documentation about a command. To look up mount just type "man mount" and you will be presented with a load of information in the terminal. This works for just about any command. Press q to exit