# Why do I only Have the Option to Delete Files Permanently?

Tags: filesystem, filemanager, trash

I have noticed that when interacting with files on other drives, I only have the option to delete files permanently, and I don't have the option to send them to the trash instead. This creates a rather risky operation where if I accidentally delete something which I did not intend, I cannot retrieve it.

How do I give other drives the option to send files to trash instead?

- OS Version: Ubuntu 21.04
- Kernel Version: 5.11.0-17-generic

This is the format for what I have in `/etc/fstab` for the drive where I am experiencing the issue:

```
UUID=<UUID_string_here> /mnt/<drive_name> ntfs auto,rw 0 0
```

**EDIT 1:** I have also tried what was said [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499345), and it did not work.

**EDIT 2:** The permissions on the `Trash-1000` folder are `drwxrwxrwx`.

**EDIT 3:** Could it be because the filesystem is NTFS that it doesn't support the trash functionality?

Comment: @Levente version info edited into main question as per your request. File manager is whatever is stock with Ubuntu - Nautilus I think. It only allows a permanent delete when I delete a file on a separate drive. If I am on the drive/partition that Ubuntu is installed on, I am able to send things to trash. For the last bits of your question, It has always behaved this way for me afaik.

Comment: Open your "other drive" in Nautilus and set it to display hidden files and directories. On my Ubuntu 20.04 the quick shortcut for that is `ctrl`+`H`. With hidden files displayed, look for a directory, similar to `.Trash-xxxx`. That's the trash for that drive. You can enter it, find stuff within it, and restore it, just like from the main trash folder. (I don't know where to configure this behavior; but it behaves like this as default on my Ubuntu 20.04) (You can even delete the `.Trash-xxxx` dir itself. Next time you delete something, it will be re-created anew.)

Comment: @Levente I see the file that you are talking about; however deleted files don't seem to be sent there. Like I said, I only have the option to delete permanently, and not to send to the trash, no matter where the trash may be.

Comment: Do a quick experiment with a (you-think-permanent) deletion. What ends up being the content? It's supposed to land in the `.Trash-xxxx/files/` subdir within.

Comment: @Levente I did this experiment, and nothing was sent to that folder. The file was simply permanently deleted.

Comment: Then let's wait for someone who knows what's going on :)

Comment: If the other drive is NTFS you have to mount it with the parameters described here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499345

Comment: Don't know, but if you install the trash-cli package, you should be able to delete to trash from the command line.

Comment: What are the owner, group, and permissions on the trash folders on your other drives? They would need to be writable by a normal user.

Comment: @PonJar It is NTFS, but I tried that, and it did not work.

Comment: Did you check if your user has an id of 1000? The command “id” will show you. Use that in fstab instead if it’s wrong. Alternatively try gid=1000 or gid=users. Others have had success with those solutions

Comment: @PonJar I do have ID 1000, but I discovered something else interesting, I am able to move files to trash if I log in as root. Even though the permissions on `.Trash-1000` are `drwxrwxrwx`, I, as an other user, am still unable to send files to it.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve tried this out in a virtual machine and I can get the trash to work with two approaches

1. With the NTFS partition not mounted and using the files app, go to other locations and select your NTFS disk. The files window will then show whatever is on the disk. Trash functionality then works for me.
2. I used this mount command

   `sudo mount -t ntfs -o users,uid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137,x-gvfs-show,utf8 /dev/sdb1 NTFS/`

This mounts the NTFS partition sdb1 at /home/username/NTFS Trash functionality works fine. I referred to this old answer of mine which focuses more on making the mount automatic. You can find it here. [Creating Trash for shared NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235979/creating-trash-for-shared-ntfs-partition/1237000#1237000)